# SQLiteOpenHelper getInstance() Method Throws Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have a DatabaseHelper class as part of my app (a snippet is below):

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int VERSION = 1;
private static DatabaseHelper mInstance;

// Get database instance
public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context c) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(c.getApplicationContext()); //fails here
    }
    return mInstance;
}

// Database Helper constructor
private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
    //this.mContext = context;
}
```

I added the getInstance() method to guarantee a singleton property, as I need to access my database in various places of my app while only ever using one instance. 
**Edit**: I initialize the helper with the code below in the very beginning of a class that extends IntentService (so it's not an activity, and it doesn't have an onCreate() method).

```
private DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
```

However, this causes my app to fail with "thread exiting with uncaught exception" and then "NullPointerException." What am I doing wrong here? Am I initializing the helper correctly?
Here's the logcat:

```
07-08 13:29:16.896  25205-25205/edu.swarthmore.cs.mdash.activitytype D/Place:﹕ in getInstance of DBHelper
07-08 13:29:16.897  25205-25205/edu.swarthmore.cs.mdash.activitytype D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-08 13:29:16.898  25205-25205/edu.swarthmore.cs.mdash.activitytype W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418f8d40)
07-08 13:29:16.910  25205-25205/edu.swarthmore.cs.mdash.activitytype E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: edu.swarthmore.cs.mdash.activitytype, PID: 25205
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service edu.swarthmore.cs.mdash.activitytype.ActivityRecognitionIntentService: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2570)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
        at edu.swarthmore.cs.mdash.activitytype.DatabaseHelper.getInstance(DatabaseHelper.java:35)
        at edu.swarthmore.cs.mdash.activitytype.ActivityRecognitionIntentService.<init>(ActivityRecognitionIntentService.java:52)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2567)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139)
```

Comment: Looks like your context may be empty

Comment: Post logcat exception.

Comment: And show where you are calling this method

Comment: Okay I added more information - hopefully that helps clear it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the method too early when initializing member variables of some `Context` class such as an `Activity` (as indicated by `private`). At that point the context has not yet been set up and calling `getApplicationContext()` will NPE due to missing base context.

`Context` is only set up just before `onCreate()` in the lifecycle. Move your initialization to `onCreate()`.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense that the context is calling the NPE. But if I want to initialize the database helper in a service class that doesn't have onCreate(), where should I put it?

Comment: Services have onCreate() too

Comment: I moved my initialization further down in the class (in onHandleIntent(), as this is an IntentService class and I'm not supposed to call onCreate() directly). But that worked, so thank you!